# Get values of all selected checkboxes and add them to Query String

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I will try to be as brief and objective as possible. I'm developing a shopping cart system and for some products categories I need to create checkboxes that corresponds to the additional products that can be added for a single product and the amount of it. I have one script to display the products by category, and if category id match with the specified number id, the additional products are recovered from the database table *additionals* and displayed in checkboxes with their price in the row of the product that belong to that category. In my page **products.php** I have the following code to display my products from database:

```
$sql = "SELECT p.product_id, p.product_name, p.product_price, 

p.category_id, c.category_name FROM products p, categories c WHERE c.category_id = p.category_id ORDER BY p.category_id, p.product_name";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$sql2 = "SELECT additional_id, additional_name, additional_price FROM additionals ORDER BY additional_name";
$stmt2 = $connection->prepare($sql2);
$stmt2->execute();

$num = $stmt->rowCount();
$category = null;

if($num>0)
{
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        extract($row);
        if($category != $category_id)
        {
            if(!is_null($category)) { echo "</table>"; }

        echo "<h1>{$category_name}</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>PRICE</th>
                <th>QUANTITY</th>";
                if($category_id == 1) echo" <th>ADDITIONALS</th>";
            echo "</tr>";

            $category = $category_id;
        }
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class='product-id' style='display: none'>{$product_id}</div>
                <div class='product-name'>{$product_name}</div></td>
                <td>&#36;{$product_price}
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='number' name='quantity' value='1' min='1' max='20'/>
            </td>";
            if($category_id == 1)
            {
                echo "<td>";
                while ($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                    extract($row);
                    echo "
                    <input type='checkbox' name='acr[]' value='{$additional_id}'/>{$additional_name} - &#36;{$additional_price} <input type='number' name='quantity_acr[]' value='1' min='1' max='5'/><br/>
                    ";
                }
                echo "</td>";
            }
            echo "<td>
                <form class='add'>
                    <button type='submit'>Add</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

With this code, my output is something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYH5z.png
The category id 1 corresponds to the Food category so, the additionals column will be displayed.
I use this jQuery code to get the values and add them to a Query String:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.add').on('submit', function()
    {
        var product_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.product-id').text();
        var product_name = $(this).closest('tr').find('.product-name').text();
        var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val();
        window.location.href = "add_to_cart.php?product_id=" + product_id + "&product_name=" + product_name + "&quantity=" + quantity;
        return false;
    });
});
```

And here is my problem. I have no idea of how to store the additional selected checkboxes products and their respective quantities in the Query String too! In **add_to_cart.php** I have the following code to get the variables from Query String, compare them in database and add the product to the SESSION:

```
if (isset($_GET['product_id']) && $_GET['product_id'] != "")
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart']))
    {
        $count = count($_SESSION['cart']);
        $product_id_session = $count++;
    }
    else
    {
        $product_id_session = 0;
    }
    $product_id = isset($_GET['product_id']) ? $_GET['product_id'] : "";
    $product_name = isset($_GET['product_name']) ? $_GET['product_name'] : "";
    $quantity = isset($_GET['quantity']) ? $_GET['quantity'] : "";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id LIKE '{$product_id}' AND product_name LIKE '{$product_name}' LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $num = $stmt->rowCount();

    if($num == 1)
    {
        if($quantity <= 0 || $quantity > 20)
        {
            header('Location: products.php?action=invalidquantity&product_name=' . $product_name);
        }
        else if(!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
        {
            $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
        }
        if(isset($_SESSION['cart']))
        {
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                extract($row);
                $columns = array
                (
                    'product_id_session' => $product_id_session,
                    'product_id' => $product_id,
                    'product_name' => $product_name,
                    'product_price' => $product_price,
                    'quantity' => $quantity
                );
            }
            $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id_session] = $columns;
            header('Location: products.php?action=added&product_name=' . $product_name);
        }
    }   
    else
    {
        redirect_to("products.php");
    }
}
```

I need to do the same with the selected checkboxes! Compare them in database with **additional_id** and insert the name and price of them in the SESSION in the respective product array, but I do not know how to do this. I hope you understood what I want to do. I'm trying this all day but my current knowledge does not allow me to pass beyond this point. I humbly ask someone to help me.

Comment: wrap the whole table in a form and use `serialize()` is easiest way to set this all up

Comment: @charlietfl By this way I can store each additional with their name, price and quantity in the SESSION array and then display each of them in the cart page?

Comment: certainly, just like any other form

Comment: @charlietfl Can you give me an example of code adapted to my system for me to understand better?

Comment: no different than any other form

Comment: @charlietfl I did not understand. How do I will get each of the checked additionals names and quantities, parse and compare it in database to add to the SESSION product array by this way?

Comment: by using `name` on form controls

Answer (score 0):

The name of the input field is  `acr[]`.  This means you will have a numerical array inside `$_GET['acr']` assuming the submit method is GET.

So you'll have `$_GET['acr'][0]`, `$_GET['acr'][1]`, etc.

You can always use `var_dump($_GET)` to see all the input values.

It might make more sense for you to use a unique identifier inside the brackets for each product type.

For example use name `acr[garlic]` or `acr[01234]` signifying a product ID.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what the OP was asking.

Comment: Are you suggesting a formulation in all my code? I'm needing to parse the additional ids of selected checkboxes along with the amount to compare them with the values in the table additionals, like I made with the products.

Answer (score 0):

try this : http://jsfiddle.net/zkky5c0f/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var allCheckbox = '';
$('input[type=\"checkbox\"]').each(function(){
    if(allCheckbox !== ''){
        allCheckbox += '-' + $(this).val(); 
    }else{
        allCheckbox +=  $(this).val(); 
    }

});
 alert(allCheckbox);
});
```

In your code it would be like:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.add').on('submit', function()
   {
    var product_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.product-id').text();
    var product_name = $(this).closest('tr').find('.product-name').text();
    var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val();
    var allCheckbox = '';
    $('input[type=\"checkbox\"]').each(function(){
     if(allCheckbox !== ''){
        allCheckbox += '-' + $(this).val(); 
     }else{
        allCheckbox +=  $(this).val(); 
     }
});
    window.location.href = "add_to_cart.php?product_id=" + product_id + "&product_name=" + product_name + "&quantity=" + quantity + "&checkbox=" + allCheckbox;
    return false;
});
```

});

Then in PHP you can simply explode the string over `-`
example :

`$checkbox = explode($_GET['checkbox']);`

hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was trying something like this, but I could not pass each selected checkbox additional with their amount for the Query String.

Comment: I have updated the answer for your code. please check

Comment: How about the quantities informed for each additional?

Comment: to store additional data you can use `data-someprop` property and then in jquery you can get it using : `$(this).data('someprop');` Please accept the answer if it worked :)